# Windows 8.1 recovery USB drive not booting at all

Tags: boot, usb, windows-8.1, bsod, uefi

I burned a Windows 8.1 iso to an 8GB USB drive but when I try to boot it from the BIOS I just get a blue screen error:

```
Recovery

Your PC needs to be repaired

The application or operating system couldn't be loaded because a required file is missing or
contains errors.

File: \windows\system32\boot\winload.efi
Error code: 0xc0000001

You'll need to use the recovery tools on your installation media. If you don't have any installation
media (like a disc or USB device), contact your system administrator or PC manufacturer.

Press Enter to try again
Press F8 for Startup Settings
Press Esc for UEFI Firmware Settings
```

[The error in question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BhubV.jpg)

I can't get past there. I can't acces the recovery options, I can't even access the install screen since after seeing the Lenovo logo all I see is this instant BSOD. Pressing F8 does absolutely nothing, and I already checked the settings and it's, indeed, set to UEFI.

Really what I'm trying to do is downgrade from Windows 10 to Windows 8.1. I have no idea why this file is supposedly corrupt since I downloaded the ISO from the official Microsoft website and used the rufus tool to copy it into the USB drive.
Yes, my computer is UEFI based. I checked and did everything correctly. When I used the tool it was set to UEFI. I also disabled the BIOS safe mode (or whatever it's called, I can't remember right now).

I downloaded the ISO twice and did the process with rufus twice, both unsuccesfull just ending up with the same blue screen error. After rebooting countless times I don't really know what to do anymore.

I have a Lenovo ideapad s145 if this helps. I really would appreciate some help.

Edit: [The ISO I downloaded.](https://www.microsoft.com/es-es/software-download/windows8ISO) Excuse me if it's in Spanish, but it's the same. I just selected regular Windows 8.1, then the language, then the 64-bit version. And this is [the tool I used.](https://rufus.ie/en_US/) [This is what the USB contents currently look like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KaG05.png)

Answer (score 0):

Since its an ISO, you should be able to mount the USB on any PC and check if the file is there.

Can you add a link to what ISO you downloaded?

I suspect that even though you boot from the USB, the system is seeing the Windows 10 filesystem and getting confused.  Make a Windows 10 recovery disk, then initialize the Windows 10 partition.  After that, install from the Windows 8 disk.

Comment: Sure, I edited my question. I added both the link to the Microsoft page from which I downloaded the ISO and to the tool I used.
Should I use a different tool? Also what do you mean to mount it to another PC? I did everything in this one since it's the only one I have and already has an operating system, and all of the files are there in the USB. I'll also add an image of what it currently looks like.

Comment: Changed to "any" PC.  I suspect it sees the winload.efi on Windows 10 and it does not work for Windows 8.  That's why I thin Win 10 has to go.